Fill null values based on unusual repeating pattern
I have a pandas df that needs to be cleaned by filling nulls in city_id and address_type fields:



City_ID
Date
State
City
Address_type




1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


Null
10/1/24
California
1002
Null


Null
10/1/24
California
House
Null


Null
Null
Null
Null
Null


Null
10/1/24
California
San Diego
Null


Null
10/1/24
California
San Diego
Null


Null
10/1/24
New York
1003
Null


Null
10/1/24
New York
Apartment
Null


Null
Null
Null
Null
Null


Null
10/1/24
New York
Queens
Null


Null
10/1/24
New York
Queens
Null


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment



This is the desired output:



City_ID
Date
State
City
Address_type




1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1001
10/1/24
Texas
Houston
House


1002
10/1/24
California
San Diego
House


1002
10/1/24
California
San Diego
House


1002
10/1/24
California
San Diego
House


1002
10/1/24
California
San Diego
House


1002
10/1/24
California
San Diego
House


1003
10/1/24
New York
Queens
Apartment


1003
10/1/24
New York
Queens
Apartment


1003
10/1/24
New York
Queens
Apartment


1003
10/1/24
New York
Queens
Apartment


1003
10/1/24
New York
Queens
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment


1004
10/1/24
Washington DC
Washington DC
Apartment



Rules:
If a city has a null value in the city column, the following rules apply:

The correct city ID will always appear in the first occurrence for that city in the 'City' column
The correct address_type will always appear in the second occurrence for that city in the 'City' column
Null for 'City' will always occur in the third entry for that city
There will always be exactly 5 entries for a city with a null

If a city does not have a null value, it will not always have 5 entries
The groups of cities with nulls occur at random through the dataset, so there will need to be a rule to stop from overfilling into another group
I am not as concerned with backfilling the correct Date, State, and City fields as long as the City_ID and Address_type are populated.
Thanks

df["City_ID"] = (
    df["City_ID"].fillna(df["City"].str.extract(r"(\d+)")[0]).ffill().astype(int)
)
df["Address_type"] = df["Address_type"].fillna(
    df.groupby("City_ID")["City"].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[1])
)
df["City"] = df.groupby("City_ID")["City"].transform(
    lambda x: x.iloc[3] if len(x) == 5 else x.loc[0]
)
df[["State", "Date"]] = df.groupby("City_ID")[["State", "Date"]].transform("first")

    City_ID     Date          State           City Address_type
0      1001  10/1/24          Texas        Houston        House
1      1001  10/1/24          Texas        Houston        House
2      1001  10/1/24          Texas        Houston        House
3      1001  10/1/24          Texas        Houston        House
4      1001  10/1/24          Texas        Houston        House
5      1002  10/1/24     California      San Diego        House
6      1002  10/1/24     California      San Diego        House
7      1002  10/1/24     California      San Diego        House
8      1002  10/1/24     California      San Diego        House
9      1002  10/1/24     California      San Diego        House
10     1003  10/1/24       New York         Queens    Apartment
11     1003  10/1/24       New York         Queens    Apartment
12     1003  10/1/24       New York         Queens    Apartment
13     1003  10/1/24       New York         Queens    Apartment
14     1003  10/1/24       New York         Queens    Apartment
15     1004  10/1/24  Washington DC  Washington DC    Apartment
16     1004  10/1/24  Washington DC  Washington DC    Apartment
17     1004  10/1/24  Washington DC  Washington DC    Apartment
18     1004  10/1/24  Washington DC  Washington DC    Apartment
19     1004  10/1/24  Washington DC  Washington DC    Apartment

